# What exactly makes us find something disgusting and something else cute?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Most people find insects disgusting and most people find cats so cute. What is the reason? What exactly makes us find something disgusting and something else cute?

Comment: Related: [Why baby animals seem "cute" to us?](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/16098/7001)